# My Edittext getting extended while typing the text

Tags: android

My Edittext its getting extend automatically while typing the text,Dont know what mistake i have done, please check my screen shot for exactly what my issue is, help me to find a solution. Thanks in advance.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/oldpass"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selectdate"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/oldpass"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip" >
            </EditText>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

check my screen shot for how its extend while typing[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to this layout definition: `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

You're basically telling that your `EditText` should fit the content. That means it will have a default size, but once you're typing in it and making it wider, it will extend according to the text it has inside.

You probably want to use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` to fit it to the screen, or play around with `android:layout_weight` to make it proportional to other layout items.

Comment: Glad it helped. Both for reputation and feedback purposes, once you get the solution you wanted, accept the answer that helped you most.

Comment: +1 for your answer and your comment "answer that helped you most".

Comment: On the left, you see the points each answer has. Below you'll find a 'tick', just click on it and it will turn green.

Answer (score 3):

your height and weight are `Wrap_content` as it adjust upon the length of the text you given

change that to fixed `dp` length

```
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: i need to centralize my edittext, if i use wrap content its not aligned properly.

Comment: this answer is correct all u have to do is assign the proper gravity value for the edittext

Comment: This solution works fine but hardcoding sizes might lead you having layout issues if you run your app on different devices with different screen sizes and densities. The best way is using a good combination of `wrap_content`, `match_parent` and `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 2):

Set `WEIGHT property` of your edittext it will not extended.

```
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/oldpass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/selectdate"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/oldpass"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip" >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is you are setting the `layout_width` of the `EditTex`t as `wrap_content`